# Make a fixed-Popup to have the same width as child-inline-block-div's

Tags: html, css

I want my popup-container-div to have the width of its content, that are inline-block-divs.
The popup-container itself is centered vertically and horizontally with position:fixed, top:50%, left:50% and transform:translate(-50%,-50%).

As you can see in the snippet, the popup doesn't take the full page-width.
Instead it looks like it's using just 50% of the page-width.
But I don't want the inline-block-divs displayed on the next line, when there's enough space the popup-div could take.

When I add a width with an high value to the child-div, like 800px, then the popup will adjust it's own width to the child's width.

Is there a possibility to have the popup centered and to take the width of it's content, without having to set fixed width-values?

```css
.popup
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #D5DFE1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0px black;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.a
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #487681;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` for this, check snippet below

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.popup {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #D5DFE1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0px black;
}
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #487681;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
<div class="popup">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
</div>
```